# codewarrior IDE is not responding back when build runs from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, codewarrior

I m trying to build a project from codewarrior IDE command line. It works fine when i run it manually on the windows slave as:

`CmdIDE.exe C:\Jenkins\build\workspace\project_name\xxxxxxxx.mcp /b /c /q`

But when i try to run the build from Jenkins nothing happens and it keeps on running. I tried to do this from a batch script using psexec but still no response. Please help if anyone has done this from jenkins.

> C:\Program Files\Freescale\CodeWarrior for Microcontrollers V6.3\bin>CmdIDE.exe 'C:\project_name\xxxxxxxx.mcp' /b /c /q
>   Freescale CodeWarrior IDE. Hit /? for help ERROR: Process Aborted. (Code 9)
>   C:\Program Files\Freescale\CodeWarrior for Microcontrollers V6.3\bin>exit 9 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Thanks in advance

Comment: Paste your whole console output from the job

Comment: Here is the output: C:\Program Files\Freescale\CodeWarrior for Microcontrollers V6.3\bin>CmdIDE.exe 'C:\project_name\xxxxxxxx.mcp' /b /c /q 

Freescale CodeWarrior IDE. Hit /? for help

ERROR: Process Aborted. (Code 9)

C:\Program Files\Freescale\CodeWarrior for Microcontrollers V6.3\bin>exit 9 

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure